# Error of Calling a templated function

Tags: c++

I have two classes like

```
class DetectedObject_OF_Kalman{} and 

template <class D, class M>
class Match{ }
```

Then I have templated function like

```
template <class D, class M>//D for DetectedObject, and M for Matched object
int find_matches (list<D*> &objects1, list<D*> &objects2, list<M*> &results, list<M*> &storage, list<D*> &unmatched1, list<D*> &unmatched2)
```

When I call that `find_matches`

```
int tracking(IplImage* fg_im)
{
    int ret_val = 0;
    list<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman*> DObjects;   
    list<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman*> TObjects;   
    list<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman*> unmatchedD;   
    list<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman*> unmatchedT;   
    list<Match<class D, class M>*> results;   
    list<Match<class D, class M>*> matchStorage;   
    list<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman *>::iterator iter;   
    list<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman*>::iterator iterFound;   
    list<Match<class D, class M>*>::iterator iterM; 

    findMatches<DetectedObject_OF_Kalman, Match>(DObjects, TObjects, results, matchStorage, unmatchedD, unmatchedT);

}
```

I got compiled errors of `findMatches` is undefined. `DetectedObject_OF_Kalman` not allowed. And class template `"Match"` is missing.
What is the correct way to call that `findMatches` function.

Comment: What do you think D and M are in this code? `list<Match<class D, class M>*> results; list<Match<class D, class M>*> matchStorage;`. To me they just seem to be undefined.

Comment: what should be the correct way?If I do like list<Match*> results;I got error at Match as "argument list for class template "Match" is missing.

Comment: Why don't you have specific class/type names here :  list<Match<class D, class M>*> results;   
    list<Match<class D, class M>*> matchStorage;

Comment: @batuman, what would be the correct way depends on what you think you are doing with `list<Match<class D, class M>*> results;`. Since that makes no sense, I'm not sure what to suggest to fix it.

Comment: @batuman Something like `list<Match<int, int>*> results;` would at least make sense, but whether it's what you want or not I don't know.

Comment: @batuman Basically you have only two options, either supply specific types for `Match` (like I did with `Match<int, int>` above), or make `tracking` a template function too.